# When I submit post request to the built-in /login of spring-security, get response "There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

My web app is build with spring-boot, spring-security. When I submit post request to the built-in /login of spring-security for authentication, I get the response "There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).".

SecurityConfig.java

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

      @Autowired
      private ReaderRepository readerRepository;

      @Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws  Exception {
        http
          .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/readingList/**").access("hasRole('READER')")
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
          .and()
          .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/myLogin")
            .failureUrl("/myLogin?error=true");
      }

      @Override
      protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) 
        throws Exception {
          auth
            .userDetailsService(new UserDetailsService() {
              @Override
              public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
                throws UsernameNotFoundException {
                return readerRepository.findOne(username);
              }
            });
      }
    }
```

myLogin.html

```
    <form name='f' th:action="@{/login}" method='POST'>
    <table>
    <tr>
      <td>User:</td>
      <td><input type='text' name='username' value='' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Password:</td>
      <td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

I suppose when I run the web app, it will redirect me to myLogin.html. When I input the correct username and password in the form, submit to /login, spring-security's some security filter will intercept the request and process the authentication using the account info configured in SecurityConfig class. But I get the response "There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404). No message available".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try explicitly specifying the login processing url of spring security on the http configure method, like "/userAuth" for example. Then, try sending a post request and checking if it still cannot find the endpoint.

Here:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws  Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/readingList/**").access("hasRole('READER')")
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/userAuth")
                .loginPage("/myLogin")
                .failureUrl("/myLogin?error=true");
    }
```

I have used [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login) back when I have learned Spring Security. Specifically on section 8.2 there is an explanation on login processing endpoints.

Comment: Is that means I will write a controller listen to this url and process the authentication myself?

Comment: No. It means that from now on Spring Security will listen for authentication parameters on that endpoint. It will take care of the controller listener by itself.

Comment: Now the authentication can be processed by Spring Security when I added the add loginProcessUrl("/userAuth") method, thanks for help!